# Delete a conversion tracking pixel from Facebook Ads Manager

Tags: facebook, tracking-pixel

Is it possible to delete a conversion tracking pixel from the Facebook Ads Manager and how? I have one pixel that I don't need anymore but I can't find an options for deletion. Is there an option which I just can't see or there's really no chance for removing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone else is wondering, too, I got this answer from Facebook:

> Unfortunately it's not possible to delete a conversion pixel once you've created it. The good news, however, is that we're removing the conversion tracking pixel in the second half of 2016. I'm unsure as to whether or not they'll be completely removed from your ad account, but be on the lookout for that update to see if you can't get rid of them then.

Comment: According to facebook support (May 2017) , it is still not possible to delete tracking pixels. See https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10154980521006620&answer_id=10155008849546620

Comment: As at 4th December 2018 it seems you still cannot delete a tracking pixel.  There is no warning when you create a pixel that it can never be deleted and it will continue collecting data even if you don't want it to.  In a Shopify scenario, for example, the pixel will be used to keep getting insights about people visiting your store, even if you don't want it to.